# How to Search for a String and replace the n to n+10 character from that string with another 10 character in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

I want to search for a string and then from that string i want to replace 10 characters with another 10 characters.

For Example,

```
/prd/edm/hadoop/ifrs/eglex/hdata/ifrs_sri_open/eglex_*_txnacbal/ods=2020_02_23/
```

i want to search for string `"ods="` and replace `"2020_02_23"` with `"2020_02_30"`

Since that date `"2020_02_23"` is not consistent i wanted to search with `"ods="` which is static and one time for a line.

Like this more lines are there in the file.

I tried:

```
cat dta_1.sh | sed 's/.*ods=//' | cut -c1-10
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried.

Comment: `cat dta_1.sh | sed 's/.*ods=//' | cut -c1-10`

but this filters all the lines even though there is not word "ods=" in that line at all like below,
2020_02_23
2020_02_23
hadoop fs
hadoop fs

Comment: Can you please add this attempted command in your question so that it can be opened again due to lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to search for string "ods=" and replace "2020_02_23" with
>   "2020_02_30"

```
sed 's|\(.*ods=\).*|\12020_02_30/|g' inputfile
```

The regex inside the parenthesis `\( \)` is reproduced by `\1`, and the string **after** `ods=` is replaced by `2020_02_30/`.

If there could be something else besides `/` after the date, then go for this:

```
sed 's|\(.*ods=\)...._.._..|\12020_02_30|g' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I've completed this using the below,

```
sed -i '/ods=/ s|ods="[^"]*"|ods='"${DATE_FORMAT2}"'|g' dta_2.sh
```

Thanks all for the response